# Angular 6 can't call HTTP service twice?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I'm at a loss, I have a service that uses `http` client to fetch data:

```
export class CategoryService {
  ...
  public getCategories(include?: string): Observable<ICategory[]> {
    return this.http.get(`/categories?include=${include}`);
  }
  ...
}
```

This is called initially from an `ngOnInit` method in another component, and works fine, the data is returned and I display it in the view.

```
export class ListCategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  public ngOnInit() {
    this._getCategories();
  }

  private _getCategories() {
    // Debug
    console.log('called getCategories');

    this.loading = true;
    this.categories = [];
    this.temp = [];
    this.catService.getCategories('products')
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.categories = response;
        this.temp = [...this.categories];
        this.loading = false;
      }, (err) => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
  ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is, when I try to call `_getCategories` again to refresh the data, I can see the method is invoked from the `console.log` output.  But the data in my view does not refresh.  The XHR request is not resent to the server.

I swear I used to be able to do this in Angular 2 & Angular 4.  But now for some reason it just doesn't work.  What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you call it? By triggering the `_getCategories()` or `getCategories()` method again?

Comment: Check chrome devTools network tab if request submitted to the server or not, 

try to call twice this._getCategories(); in ngOnInit and check the behavior 

are you sure that the second time ( not the initial request )  logs your comment

Comment: Check whether the call hits your backend. And can you update where you called?

Comment: are you using trackBy ?

Comment: The network request is never sent.  I'm calling `_getCategories()`  again.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a specific issue with ngx-datatable, and my misunderstanding of the library, possibly JS.

Simply setting `this.categories = response;` wasn't allowing the table to be updated with new data, I needed to use the JS spread operator.

Like this:

```
this.categories = [...response];
```

If I don't do this, the data isn't updated.  Maybe someone can comment on the reason behind this.